# Stored Procedure Select as Argument

Tags: stored-procedures, select

Is the following possible:

EXEC sp_Edu3_DeleteTreeStructure (SELECT TreeStructureId FROM TreeStructures)

The SP normally takes one argument. What I want is that the SP is executed for each TreeStructureId found by the Query.

thx, Lieven Cardoen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CURSOR to do this.

```
DECLARE @treeStructureId int

DECLARE TreeStructureCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        TreeStructureId
    FROM
        TreeStructures

OPEN TreeStructureCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM TreeStructureCursor
INTO @treeStructureId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_Edu3_DeleteTreeStructure(@treeStructureId)

    FETCH NEXT FROM TreeStructureCursor
    INTO @treeStructureId
END

CLOSE TreeStructureCursor
DEALLOCATE TreeStructureCursor
```

Comment: Thx, Robin, I knew I could do it with a cursor but I was wondering if it could be done without a cursor. (I don't think it can be done...)

Comment: You could change your SELECT statement to return XML containing all of the ID's and then modify your Stored Proc to accept this XML as it's parameter and work with 1-many id's. You're right though, a stored procedure cannot do as you ask. A function is closer, but will be unable to delete the data.